# Mac does not sleep when lid is closed after installing Insomniax

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, sleep-wake

I've installed Insomniax on my MacBook Air. After I tap "Disable lid sleep" my Mac can't sleep.

I tried to turn off this function by it no helped. When I close and open the lid, then run `pmset -g` in Terminal, I see

```
sleep 1 (sleep prevented by fud, powerd)
```

How can I fix this?

macOS Sierra 10.13.3

Comment: Is your problem with Insomniax?  Have you tried talking to them about it?